# How to effectively rewrite $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x}-1}{x}$ to properly assess its value

Tags: limits, elementary-functions

I am tasked with evaluating the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x}-1}{x}$$

There are two things I have tried. The first, substituting $x$ for $\ln t$ gave me

$$\lim_{x \to o} \frac{t-1}{\ln t}$$

But I did not know what to do from there. The other attempt was using the numerator's conjugate like so:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{t^{2}-1}{\left(t+1\right)\ln t}$$

But again, I did not know where to go from there. What do you suggest I try?

Cheers

Comment: How do you define $e^x$ ?

Comment: @lhf The base is Euler's number, an irrational number written simply as e. So I would define $e^{x}$ like so, multiplied with itself x amount of times. Therefore, as x approaches zero, it ought to be $e^{0}=1$, right?

Comment: The interpretation of $e^x$ as $e$ multiplied by itself $x$ amount of times only makes sense when $x$ is a natural number; outside of that special situation, that interpretation is nonsense.

Comment: For further discussion on this point see [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846836).

Comment: Yes, it's cool that you know the name. But how is it _defined_? What mathematical property decides what exact number it is in your book?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\log (t+1)$, so when $x\to 0$ than $t\to 0$, and the limit converts into:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t}{\log (t+1)}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{\log(t+1)}{t}}=\\
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{t} \log(t+1)}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{\log (1+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}}=\frac{1}{\log e}=1$$

Since $$e:=\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x=\lim_{t\to 0}(1+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hôpital's rule

$\begin{align}&\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(e^{x}-1)}{x}\quad(\frac{0}{0}-\text{form})\\&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x}}{1}\\&=e^0\\&=1
\end{align}$

Comment: The original limit is the definition of the derivative of $e^x$  So your answer is circular

Comment: Is this the reason for Downvote? I think OP doesn't give any appropriate definition of $e$.

Comment: I didn’t downvote

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of limits, whenever the quotient rule yields "0/0", you can either l'Hopital's Rule or Taylor Series.

Using l'Hopital's Rule, we have

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^x-1)'}{(x)'}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x}{1}=1.
$$

Since the $n$-th Taylor polynomial of $e^x$ about $x=0$ is given by
$$
T_n(x)=1+x+\frac{x%2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}.
$$
we have, for $n\ge 2$:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{T_n(x)-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\left[1+\frac{x}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}\right]=1.
$$

Alternatively, one can also notice that if $f(x)=e^x$, then the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}
$$
represents the derivative of $f$ at $x=0$. Since $f'(x)=e^x$, we get
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f'(0)=e^0=1.
$$

Comment: But the asked limit is just the definition of the derivative of the exponential in zero, so.. Is not using Taylor's a circular argument?